# Fossil: recognise changes while repo closed

Tags: dvcs, fossil

I know, I should only change files in a project, when the repository is opened. But I now tried to see what happens when I change a file when the repo is closed, because I will often do that, because I'm going to forget to open repos. It's inconvenient ...

Now I see what happens: changes are not recognised. Doing a commit, I get the message "nothing has changed" ... which is not true.

What can I do to make fossil recognise missed changes?

Comment: Now I tried the same thing again. This time, when re-opening the repo, I'm asked whether I wish to "overwrite" the changed file ... Overwriting means overwriting the new file with the old one! (Just in case s.o. else is wondering ...) --- choosing No, the changes remain intact, and a commit recognises the changes. So I wonder why this did not work the first time I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you close the repository? When you do `fossil open`, fossil will try to deploy the latest version. Maybe it has overwritten your files…

You should use `open .... --keep` if you don't want to harm your working directory.

As a comparison with git (seems that it's your background):

- in git, each working directory has its own `.git` folder. Multiple working directories for the same repository are typically hardlinked.
- in fossil, each working directory contains a file named `_FOSSIL_` or maybe `.fossil` depending on your version. It contains both a pointer to the repository (the object database) plus workingdir-specific data (what you'd call HEAD, stash, uncommitted additions/deletions/renames). `close` will delete that file. So, in git terms, it's like if you did `git clone --bare . some_other_folder.git` and then recursive `rmdir .git`. You still have the project history somewhere, but all information about your working tree is lost.

Comment: Why not? From the docs, as far as I read, I understood it's the normal workflow. Open, change files, close. So is it rather Open, finish project, close? Can I have several repos open at once? I might have to read the full docs after all ...

Comment: You never have to close, unless your project is finished or you abandon a working tree. `close` detaches the working directory from the repository (in git terms, it would move the `.git` folder away). Open, change files, commit, change files, commit, etc. You can have a repository open at multiple locations at once if you want.